# How to run an Apache Camel integration with Camel K containing: XML file & .java file

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel

Document of Apache Camel K guides how to run an integration wroten by XML. But when I need to write custom code in Java (processors, transform), I can not find the way to run them together. So, have Camel K supported this features? If it have, how can I do that?

Comment: Does https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/latest/languages/java.html not answer your question?

Comment: @coderanger, thanks but it only has the way to run only java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix languages like

```
kamel run --name my-app routes.xml routes.java
```

Then if your need is to write custom processors in java, then you can bind such processors to the camel registry from your configure method like

```
getContext().getRegistry().bind("myProcessor", new Processor() { ... }
```

or by annotating methods with @BindToRegistry in tour RouteBuilder class like

```
@BindToRegistry("my-processor")
Processor myProcessor() {
    return exchange -> { ... }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://github.com/apache/camel-k/tree/master/examples/polyglot